# foreach Loop is repeating last item in array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

I am trying to write a foreach loop that will send a separate report by mail for each array element, but it keeps outputting the last element only.  I've tried writing this so many ways that I think I'm starting to repeat myself.  Please help.

```
$items = array(1 => 1, 2 => 2, 3 => 3, 7 => 4, 8 => 5,9 => 6, 17 => 8, 18 => 338, 19 => 50, 23 => 52, 11 => 7, 16 => 44,  4 => 11, 5 => 22, 6 => 33);

foreach ($items as $id => $number) {
//I am querying a pervasive database here
$wtdVar = $dbx->getOne('SELECT SUM(sales) FROM table WHERE date1 >= '.$wkstart3.' AND date2 <= '.$today3.' AND category <> \'ABC\' AND number = '.$number);

if (DB::isError($wtdVar)) {
    echo '<div class="error">Error: - '.$wtdVar->getDebugInfo().'</div>';
}

//get the goal for the week so far, use date variables with 2 at the end for postgres queries
$wtdgoal = $db->getOne("SELECT SUM(goal) FROM table2 WHERE id = $id AND gdate BETWEEN '$wkstart2' AND '$today2'");
if (DB::isError($wtdgoal)) {
    echo '<div class="error">Error: - '.$wtdgoal->getDebugInfo().'</div>';}
}
```

There are 15 items in the array, and the e-mail of the report works just fine, but the data in the report is the last item 15x.  There are more data, and with a static variable where I have the array elements it works perfectly, but I need it to loop because I have to use this data at many places.

Comment: You are overriding at each iteration of your foreach loop the variables `$wtdVar` and `$wtdgoal`, so if you expect to get your data in `$wtdVar` or in `$wtdgoal`, you get only the last result, corresponding to the last iteration.

Comment: @tmuguet could you please be a little more specific and give an example of how it should be written?  This is one of the areas of php that I really struggle with.

Comment: I can't be more specific unless you put the code where you use those variables (I guess, after the foreach loop).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up arrays to contain all your retrieved values.

```
$wtdVars = array();
$wtdgoals = array();

foreach ($items as $id => $number) {
    //I am querying a pervasive database here
    $wtdVar = $dbx->getOne('SELECT SUM(sales) FROM table WHERE date1 >= '.$wkstart3.' AND date2 <= '.$today3.' AND category <> \'ABC\' AND number = '.$number);

    $wtdVars[] = $wtdVar;

    if (DB::isError($wtdVar)) {
        echo '<div class="error">Error: - '.$wtdVar->getDebugInfo().'</div>';
    }

    //get the goal for the week so far, use date variables with 2 at the end for postgres queries
    $wtdgoal = $db->getOne("SELECT SUM(goal) FROM table2 WHERE id = $id AND gdate BETWEEN '$wkstart2' AND '$today2'");

    $wtdgoals[] = $wtdgoal;

    if (DB::isError($wtdgoal)) {
        echo '<div class="error">Error: - '.$wtdgoal->getDebugInfo().'</div>';
    }
}
```

Then presumably in your report you have a loop that keeps using `$wtdVar` or `$wtdgoal` - instead this should use `$wtdVars[$i]` and `$wtdgoals[$i]` where `$i` is a variable starting at zero that increments with each iteration of the loop in the report.